# Why does my input go crazy and repeat because of my substring?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a pi memorization game, and a while back I ran into a problem but found a solution, however my solution, deleting the start of the input after a certain point, turns out is messing up the order of things. For example, I currently have it set to delete the start at 10 but once I get to 3.141592653 it shows up .1415926533 instead of the last number being 5. Why does it keep replacing things and messing up the order? Also is there an easier way to do this, I'm very new to JavaScript and don't know a lot of alternatives. It's not finished obviously and I cut some irrelevant parts out but everything should work

I messed around with substrings and found out a way that works how I want but it still messes up and breaks how I described above. I don't even know where to start

(edit. It has come to my attention that some people need more context on the previous problem that I'm fixing by doing this. I have a system that, if the player gets the order of pi wrong, then the entire input resets, however before doing that the input adds the correct number in place of the wrong answer, but past ~29 units, when the units need to be pushed backwards to make room for the new units, the correct answer just doesn't show up. To fix this problem I decided to just not make the units move backwards, by deleting the first unit)

(edit 2) The 10 units is just a place holder so that I didn't need to type 29 characters for me to check if it works, I just chose a random number that was small enough for me to be quick but long enough that I can see some effects)

```js
   const input = document.getElementById("input-field")

input.addEventListener("beforeinput", myFunction)

const numbers = "1234567890.".split("")

input.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
        const position = event.target.selectionStart
        if (position > 10){
        input.value = input.value.substring(1)

    }});


function myFunction(event) {
    if (event.data && !numbers.includes(event.data)) {
        event.preventDefault()
    } else if (event.data) {
        const charno = input.value.length

    if (pi[charno] != event.data) { 
            input.disabled = true
            event.preventDefault()
            
            function1()

            setTimeout(somethingFunction, 2000)

        }
    }
}


function function1() {input.value += pi[input.value.length]}

function somethingFunction() {  
    input.disabled = false
    input.value = ''

}


const pi = '3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459\
2307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231\
7253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659\
3344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726\
0249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330\
5305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931\
0511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664\
3086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669\
4051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301\
4654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130\
9960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642\
5223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473\
0359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300\
1927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952\
0353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295\
3311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285\
8361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534\
6462080466842590694912933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533\
8243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992\
4586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165\
3449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746\
7289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115\
7352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219\
2221842725502542568876717904946016534668049886272327917860857843838279679766\
8145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528\
5022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573\
9624138908658326459958133904780275900994657640789512694683983525957098258226\
2052248940772671947826848260147699090264013639443745530506820349625245174939\
9651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753\
9284681382686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958\
4865383673622262609912460805124388439045124413654976278079771569143599770012\
9616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467\
6788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743\
2411251507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330\
8617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998\
9487226588048575640142704775551323796414515237462343645428584447952658678210\
5114135473573952311342716610213596953623144295248493718711014576540359027993\
4403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191\
0484810053706146806749192781911979399520614196634287544406437451237181921799\
9839101591956181467514269123974894090718649423196156794520809514655022523160\
3881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503\
0680384477345492026054146659252014974'
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field">
```

Comment: Wat is the issue you're tryign to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `keyup`-event you do

```
   input.value = input.value.substring(1);
```

That will remove the first character, so "3.141592653" becomes ".141592653".

And in `myFunction` you do

```
const charno = input.value.length;
```

You never compensates for that you potentially have removed characters. The length will, after a while, always be 10.

So, when you in `function1` do

```
  input.value += pi[input.value.length];
```

You get the wrong character, since you never compensate for the characters that you have removed. Since `[input.value.length` never can be larger than 10, you get the character in index 10 from "3.141592653", which is "3" (remember the index is zero based).

### *Simplified solution*

Here is an example of how it could be solved. I use the `beforeinput` event (before the browser has updated the field) to verify that only allowed characters are added, and the verification that it is correct in the ´input´ event (after the browser has updated the field).

I don't understand why you want to limit the field to only 10 characters. It just makes the code more complicated, because you have to keep track of how many characters you removed. I think a better solution is to set the size of the input field, so that it doesn't show more characters than you want, but keep the entire input string. It makes the verification and code much easier. It is admittedly a waste of cpu cycles to compare the entire string for each new character, but it is still so fast that I don't feel it is worth optimizing.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input-field');

input.addEventListener('beforeinput', validateInput);
input.addEventListener('input', verifyInput);

const validCharacters = '1234567890.';

function validateInput(event) {
  if (event.data && validCharacters.indexOf(event.data) < 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function verifyInput(event) {
  const userInput = input.value;
  const userLength = userInput.length;
  const wantedInput = pi.slice(0, userLength);

  if (userInput !== wantedInput) {
    const posEnd = wantedInput.length + 1;
    input.value = wantedInput;

    // Make sure cursor is at the last position
    input.setSelectionRange(posEnd, posEnd);
    input.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      input.value = '';
      input.disabled = false;
      // Since the focus was lost when the field was disabled,
      // it should be given the focus again.
      input.focus();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

const pi =
  '3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459\
2307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231\
7253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659\
3344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726\
0249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330\
5305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931\
0511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664\
3086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669\
4051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301\
4654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130\
9960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642\
5223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473\
0359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300\
1927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952\
0353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295\
3311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285\
8361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534\
6462080466842590694912933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533\
8243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992\
4586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165\
3449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746\
7289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115\
7352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219\
2221842725502542568876717904946016534668049886272327917860857843838279679766\
8145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528\
5022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573\
9624138908658326459958133904780275900994657640789512694683983525957098258226\
2052248940772671947826848260147699090264013639443745530506820349625245174939\
9651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753\
9284681382686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958\
4865383673622262609912460805124388439045124413654976278079771569143599770012\
9616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467\
6788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743\
2411251507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330\
8617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998\
9487226588048575640142704775551323796414515237462343645428584447952658678210\
5114135473573952311342716610213596953623144295248493718711014576540359027993\
4403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191\
0484810053706146806749192781911979399520614196634287544406437451237181921799\
9839101591956181467514269123974894090718649423196156794520809514655022523160\
3881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503\
0680384477345492026054146659252014974';
```

```css
input { width:10ch; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" />
```

I included another example, which instead of deleting everything, corrects what the user typed, with an audible indication.

```js
var ctxAudio;

function beep(frequency, time) {
  // You get a warning if you create a AudioContext before the user has interacted
  // with the page. By creating it when it is used, that solves that problem.
  // The browser can limit how many you can create, and if so, no sound will be produced.
  // By only createing the context one time, solves that problem.
  if (!ctxAudio) ctxAudio = new AudioContext();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var oscillator = ctxAudio.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = 'sine';
    oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
    oscillator.connect(ctxAudio.destination);
    oscillator.start();
    setTimeout(function () {
      oscillator.stop();
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
}

const input = document.getElementById('input-field');

input.addEventListener('beforeinput', validateInput);
input.addEventListener('input', verifyInput);

const validCharacters = '1234567890.';

async function validateInput(event) {
  if (event.data && validCharacters.indexOf(event.data) < 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await beep(200, 200);
  }
}

async function verifyInput(event) {
  const userInput = input.value;
  const userLength = userInput.length;
  const wantedInput = pi.slice(0, userLength);

  if (userInput !== wantedInput) {
    const posEnd = wantedInput.length + 1;
    input.value = wantedInput;
    input.disabled = true;
    await beep(1000, 200);
    input.disabled = false;
    input.focus();
  }
}

const pi =
  '3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459\
2307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231\
7253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659\
3344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726\
0249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330\
5305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931\
0511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664\
3086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669\
4051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301\
4654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130\
9960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642\
5223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473\
0359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300\
1927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952\
0353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295\
3311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285\
8361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534\
6462080466842590694912933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533\
8243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992\
4586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165\
3449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746\
7289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115\
7352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219\
2221842725502542568876717904946016534668049886272327917860857843838279679766\
8145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528\
5022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573\
9624138908658326459958133904780275900994657640789512694683983525957098258226\
2052248940772671947826848260147699090264013639443745530506820349625245174939\
9651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753\
9284681382686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958\
4865383673622262609912460805124388439045124413654976278079771569143599770012\
9616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467\
6788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743\
2411251507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330\
8617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998\
9487226588048575640142704775551323796414515237462343645428584447952658678210\
5114135473573952311342716610213596953623144295248493718711014576540359027993\
4403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191\
0484810053706146806749192781911979399520614196634287544406437451237181921799\
9839101591956181467514269123974894090718649423196156794520809514655022523160\
3881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503\
0680384477345492026054146659252014974';
```

```css
input { width: 10ch;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first solution worked perfectly and I didn't need to jump through all the hoops that I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @42HitchHikers I know it can be frustrating trying to find the solution. Since you showed with the attached code what you have tried, it was easier to find what was wrong. Good luck with the game and the memorization :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use substring instead of splitting

```js
function cut() {
    let pi = document.getElementById("pi").innerText;
    let start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    let end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    if (isNaN(start) || isNaN(end) || (start === "") || (end === "")) {
        alert("Please fill the numbers");
        return;
    }
    start = parseInt(start);
    end = parseInt(end);
    if (start > end) {
        alert("start cannot be greater than end");
        return;
    }
    if ((start < 0) || (end < 0)) {
        alert("negatives are not supported");
        return;
    }
    let dotlessPI = pi.replace(".", "");
    if (end > dotlessPI.length) {
        alert("out of bounds");
    }
    let substring = ((start === 0) ? "" : dotlessPI.substring(0, start));
    if (end + 1 < dotlessPI.length) substring += dotlessPI.substring(end + 1);
    if (start > 0) substring = substring.substring(0, 1) + "." + substring.substring(1);
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = substring;
}

document.getElementById("cut").addEventListener("click", cut);
```

```html
<p id="pi">3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510 58209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679</p>
<input type="number" placeholder="start" id="start">
<input type="number" placeholder="end" id="end">
<input type="button" value="cut" id="cut">
<div id="output"></div>
```